# Is it possible to convert an elasticsearch query into something that can apply the same filtering logic over hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

We have an architecture that uses both elasticsearch and hadoop for near realtime and batch processing concerns respectively. We ingest data and write to both systems so synchronization is already taken care of, provided some lag in storing the rows into HDFS.

Calls for UI content will query elasticsearch using the query DSL. These queries use many of the bells and whistles of the elasticsearch suite like custom analyzers, match phrases, and others that don't have an equivalent in hive or mapreduce.

One of our batch processes we're moving to HDFS to do a full export of all the rows matching an elasticsearch query needs to generate the same resulting data as the query sent to elasticsearch but avoid calling elasticsearch (as is done in es-hadoop) to avoid a performance hit on our elasticsearch cluster.

Is there any generic tool or process of converting a complex elasticsearch query to something that can apply the same filtering logic in hadoop? We don't need to consider aggregations or anything like that, just query filtering.

Comment: What Hadoop tools do you currently have? Spark and Hive can get pretty far, but you might need UDFs to do anything complex

Comment: We're using Hive 1.2.1 in an HDP installation. No spark tools as of now. We have considered writing a UDF that will run after filtering the data with simple predicates in our filter (e.g. id == 123, value > 45). We can split the resulting candidate set into smaller batches where we will then spin up a lucene instance in memory and run the translated es full-text queries against those records. That will give us an exact match in hadoop but is a little cumbersome and I hoped to get some simpler ideas from the community on how they've approached it.

Comment: HDP has had Spark for at least 2 years now, but that wouldn't prevent you from downloading it yourself and configuring it to run a YARN job (you don't need a "Spark cluster"). Spark can include Lucene and CoreNLP libraries, so that's my suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the info @cricket_007 . We've have yet to really use spark but I'm imagining that's the road we'll be going down as well.

Answer (score 0):

We were dealing with a similar situation where we had to apply filtering on client side with the data received as well as on the back end side with Elasticsearch. We came up with our own way of defining a filter as an expression.

For example: if((name == Jane && age > 18) || (name == John && age <18)), would be represented as OR(AND(EQ(name:Jane),GT(age:18)))/AND),(AND(EQ(name:John),LT(age:18)))/AND)/OR).

We then use this to get ES query or any other query format you want by parsing the expression.

Comment: Interesting, but how do you handle full text queries? For example, if I have a pattern analyser on a field that splits tokens by non alphanumeric fields and you run a compound match_pharse query on that? There is really no simple if statement equivalent to those type of queries. Especially if you're doing a match that isn't a filter that instead returns a score.

Comment: You can define your own operations, along with GT, LT something like SPLIT(name:value). It is up to you, how you want to define this and what queries you want to generate.

Comment: If we were only implementing a few of the elasticsearch query types then a solution like this would be nice to handle translations between the two databases but we would need to write and maintain operations for practically the entire elasticsearch query DSL which is what I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: Yes that would be a different project by itself. There is something called as Query Builder. It may be helpful.